# IdentityServerOptions PublicOrigin

Tags: c#, identityserver4

Slowly migrating system up from .net core 2.1 to 3.1.
While updating IdentityServer4 to 3.1 version.
I've stucked into problem method AddIdentityServer where options are specified..

```
var builder = services.AddIdentityServer(options =>
{             
    (!string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(identityServerSettingsConfig.PublicOrigin))
    {
        options.PublicOrigin = identityServerSettingsConfig.PublicOrigin;
    }
})
```

> Error: '`IdentityServerOptions`' does not contain a definition for '`PublicOrigin`' and no accessible extension method '`PublicOrigin`' accepting a first argument of type '`IdentityServerOptions`' could be found

Installed packages:

```
    <PackageReference Include="IdentityServer4" Version="4.1.2" />
    <PackageReference Include="IdentityServer4.AccessTokenValidation" Version="3.0.1" />
    <PackageReference Include="IdentityServer4.AspNetIdentity" Version="4.1.2" />
    <PackageReference Include="IdentityServer4.EntityFramework" Version="2.5.3" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore.App" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity.EntityFrameworkCore" Version="5.0.5" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity.UI" Version="3.1.0" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.NewtonsoftJson" Version="3.1.0" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Design" Version="3.1.0">
```

Comment: I think your `AddIdentityServer` options callback is missing an `if` keyword.

Comment: See this: https://github.com/IdentityServer/IdentityServer4/issues/4535

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `IdentityServerOptions.PublicOrigin` property was removed in IdentityServer4 1.0 [back in 2016](https://github.com/IdentityServer/IdentityServer4/releases/tag/1.0.0).

This GitHub issue is asking the same question as yourself: https://github.com/IdentityServer/IdentityServer4/issues/4535

One of IdentityServer's authors said it was removed and explained why - and how you can work-around it (**assuming** you actually need it, I mention this because *you probably don't* need to restore this functionality):

> **leastprivilege** commented on 19 Jun 2020:
>
> It's gone. It was a hack - please use the forwarded headers approach in ASP.NET Core from now on.

The workaround is to add a middleware step that calls `HttpContextExtensions.SetIdentityServerOrigin` at the beginning of your pipeline, so it should look *something like this*:

- In the code-block below, add the code between the `//-------` comments.
- I included other `Configure` pipeline/appBuilder methods from one of my own IS4 projects so you can see a complete example.

```cs
using IdentityServer4.Extensions; // For IS4's `HttpContextExtensions`

public class Startup
{
    // ...

    public void Configure( IApplicationBuilder app, IWebHostEnvironment env, IHostApplicationLifetime applicationLifetime )
    {
        _ = app
            //-------------------------------- Add the code below this line
            .Use( async (ctx, next) =>
            {
                ctx.SetIdentityServerOrigin( "https://example.com" );
                await next();
            })
            //-------------------------------- Add the code above this line

            .UseCors()
            .UseAuthentication()
            .UseOpenApi()
            .UseSwaggerUi3()
            .UseIdentityServer()
            .UseRouting()
            .UseAuthorization()
            .UseEndpoints( routeBuilder =>
            {
                _ = routeBuilder.MapControllers();
            } )
            .UseStaticFiles();
    }
}
```